# NodeJS mysql2 connection in separate file stops soon

Tags: node.js, express, connection

> connection.js

```
let mysql = require('mysql2');
let pool = mysql.createPool({
  host:'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  database: '',
  password: '',
  connectionTimeout: 10000
}).promise()

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  console.log('connected to database')
});

pool.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err.code);
});

module.exports = {
  getConnection: () => {
    return pool.getConnection()
  }
};
```

> other_file.js

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {

    const conn = await connWrapper.getConnection();

    let [courses] = await conn.execute('SELECT * FROM courses');
    courses = courses;

    //database stuff here and page rendering etc

});
```

If I load the page for the first time, it works, however after just a few seconds it stops working and the page won't load anymore, that even if I remove connectionTimeout.
Also, how come that I do not receive logs from pool.getConnection and pool.on('error').
There aren't logs in the console whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to release connection back to the pool after you no longer need it. Default pool config id `connectionLimit: 10, queueLimit: 0`, so your first 10 requests use all available connections in the pool and later requests are stuck at `await connWrapper.getConnection();` line waiting for previous connections to be available.

Example returning connections to the pool:

```js
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const conn = await connWrapper.getConnection();
  try { 
    const [courses] = await conn.execute('SELECT * FROM courses');
    //...
  } 
  finally {
    conn.release(); // no need to await here, .release() is sync call
  }  
});
```

Or you can just use `.execute()` helper on a pool:

```js
// add this to connection.js:
// execute: (...args) => pool.execute(...args)

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const [courses] = await connWrapper.execute('SELECT * FROM courses');
  // ...
});
```